# How to count a boolean in grouped Spark data frame

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to count how many of records are true in a column from a grouped Spark dataframe but I don't know how to do that in python. For example, I have a data with a `region`, `salary` and `IsUnemployed` column with `IsUnemployed` as a Boolean. I want to see how many unemployed people in each region.  I know we can do a `filter` and then `groupby` but I want to generate two aggregation at the same time as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F  
data.groupby("Region").agg(F.avg("Salary"), F.count("IsUnemployed"))
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is a plain `CAST` (C style where `TRUE` -> 1, `FALSE` -> 0) with `SUM`:

```
(data
    .groupby("Region")
    .agg(F.avg("Salary"), F.sum(F.col("IsUnemployed").cast("long"))))
```

A little bit more universal and idiomatic solution is `CASE WHEN` with `COUNT`:

```
(data
    .groupby("Region")
    .agg(
        F.avg("Salary"),
        F.count(F.when(F.col("IsUnemployed"), F.col("IsUnemployed")))))
```

but here it is clearly an overkill.

Comment: Does the second approach run slower or does Catalyst optimize both to roughly similar bytecode?